# Pandas - Multiple Stocks Groupby for OHLC

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby, resampling

I have a .csv file in following format. There is no header, I am just writing for the same of understanding

```
time,stockname,price

09:00:00, ABC, 100
09:00:00, XYZ, 500
09:01:00, ABC, 101
09:01:00, XYZ, 499
```

and goes on

I want to do something like groupby resampling(15 minutes) of price such that the end dataframe has all stocks OHLC time based and I can pass stock name and time and get OHLC columns, which I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're after -- an expected output would be useful.

In any case, [pd.Grouper](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) is great for grouping datetime indices by time intervals. In the example below I generate some sample data that looks like your sample data and do some grouping.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate some data
some_dates = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', periods=10, freq='5min')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=some_dates)
df.index.name = 'time'
df['stock_name'] = ['ABC', 'XYZ'] * 5
df['price'] = (np.random.rand(10) * 100).round(2)

print(df)

time                   stock_name  price        
2017-01-01 00:00:00    ABC         5.26
2017-01-01 00:05:00    XYZ         68.13
2017-01-01 00:10:00    ABC         91.76
2017-01-01 00:15:00    XYZ         21.16
2017-01-01 00:20:00    ABC         75.69
2017-01-01 00:25:00    XYZ         21.16
2017-01-01 00:30:00    ABC         80.25
2017-01-01 00:35:00    XYZ         4.83
2017-01-01 00:40:00    ABC         10.07
2017-01-01 00:45:00    XYZ         20.67

# do some grouping: e.g by 15 minute intervals & by stock_name
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='15min'), df['stock_name']]).max()

time                stock_name price
2017-01-01 00:00:00 ABC        91.76
2017-01-01 00:00:00 XYZ        68.13
2017-01-01 00:15:00 ABC        75.69
2017-01-01 00:15:00 XYZ        21.16
2017-01-01 00:30:00 ABC        80.25
2017-01-01 00:30:00 XYZ        4.83
2017-01-01 00:45:00 XYZ        20.67
```

Comment: how would you do ohlc() ? max() works but ohlc() doesn't